# Form Validation angular/bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-validation

Here's [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/69we9h7g/1/)

Not able to understand that why the required validation is not working ??

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <form name="myform" class="form form-horizontal" novalidate>
            <fieldset class="fieldset" ng-show="payment == 'bankAccount'" class="form-group clearfix">
                <ul class="form-group">
                    <li ng-class="{
                'has-error':  myform.routingNumber.$invalid,
                'has-success':myform.routingNumber.$valid}">
                        <label for="routingNumber">Bank Routing Number</label>
                        <div class="" ng-show="myform.routingNumber.$error.required"> <span class="help-block">Please enter routing number</span>

                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="routingNumber" class="form-control" required/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide an [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for the angular validation on the form to kick in.

Try:-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="routingNumber" name="routingNumber" class="form-control" required/>
```

On a side note:- there is no use of using `label for` without using id on the target input.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VLOEfp?p=preview)**

Comment: @future you don't have "myctrl" controller declared in your javascript. See the console log.

Comment: @future I added a demo as well. :), hope that helps. sorry i hate fiddle, plnkr is much better

Comment: thanks very much . Actually in my previous work validation was working for name attribute (http://jsfiddle.net/FeS4A/55/)
So i was trying same over here

Comment: @future oh yeah i see, infact you had ng-model there as well, how did you miss it...